# how to find the distinct names (in column 1) whose weight (in column 2) always increased over the the weeks (in column 3) in Big Query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-manipulation, data-wrangling

I have a big query result which shows the weight of each person over many weeks, and I want to find the names of the people whose weight always increased over the weeks. Below is the a sample data.

```
    name        week        weight
    tom         2020W10     76
    tom         2020W09     75
    tom         2020W08     74
    jane        2020W10     65
    jane        2020W09     65
    jane        2020W08     64
```

So in the case of the above sample data, I would only want to see Tom in my result since his weight always increased over the dates. In my original data set, I have 10,000 names and more than 10 weeks, so it is really hard do to do with a more brute force approach. I was thinking of using the the regression function in Big query, but then I would have to do as many regressions as I have unique names.  I would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `lag()` and aggregation:

```
with t AS (
      SELECT 'tom' AS name, '2020W10' AS week, 76 AS weight UNION ALL
      select 'tom' , '2020W09' , 75 UNION ALL
      select 'tom' , '2020W08' , 74 UNION ALL
      select 'jane' , '2020W10' , 65 UNION ALL
      select 'jane' , '2020W09' , 65 UNION ALL
      select 'jane' , '2020W08' , 64
    )
select t.name
from (select t.*, lag(weight) over (partition by name order by week) as prev_weight
      from t
     ) t
group by t.name
having countif(prev_weight >= weight) = 0 ;
```

Comment: hmm, this seems to select both tom and jane while I only want tom to be in the result. do you have any idea why? Also can this work if we dont always have the same week numbers for each name , and also we there are leaps in the weeks numbers such as moving from 2020W08 to 2020W10 ( skipping the 9th week) ? I have put the code in the following comment for you to be able to reproduce it .

Comment: with t AS (
  SELECT 'tom' AS name,  '2020W10' AS week, 76 AS weight UNION ALL
select   'tom'  ,        '2020W09'  ,       75           UNION ALL
select   'tom'  ,        '2020W08'  ,       74           UNION ALL
select   'jane' ,        '2020W10'  ,       65           UNION ALL
select   'jane' ,        '2020W09'  ,       65           UNION ALL
select   'jane' ,        '2020W08'  ,       64 
)
select t.name
from (select t.*,
             lag(weight) over (partition by name order by week) as prev_weight
      from t
     ) t
group by t.name
having countif(prev_weight <= 0) = 0